# dojox/mobile/Badge not rendered in custom ListItem

Tags: mobile, dojo, listitem, badge

This is my template for a custom `ListItem`:

```
var template =
    "<div>" +
    "       <div style='display: inline;' data-dojo-attach-point='labelNode'></div>" +
    "       <div data-dojo-type='dojox/mobile/Badge' data-dojo-props='value:${size}' style='display: inline; position: absolute; right: 100px;'></div>" +
    "</div>";
```

The html is created correctly, i.e.:

```
<div data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/Badge" data-dojo-props="value:37" style="display: inline; position: absolute; right: 100px;"></div>
```

but it's not visible on the page.
I tried to place the exact same code elsewhere in the page and it works.

### UPDATE

Some other code and information.
I have a `dojox/mobile/EdgeToEdgeStoreList` and I want to use my custom `ListItem` rather than the default one. For example, I set the `background-color` on a property and I want to replace the original `rightText` with a `Badge`.

This is the fullcode of `CustomListItem`:

```
define([
    "dojox/mobile/ListItem",
    "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
    "dojox/mobile/Badge",
    "dojo/_base/declare"
], function (ListItem, TemplatedMixin, Badge, declare) {
    var template =
        "<div class='areaDone${done}'>" +
        "       <div style='display: inline;' data-dojo-attach-point='labelNode'></div>" +
        "       <div data-dojo-type='dojox/mobile/Badge' data-dojo-props='value:${size}' style='display: inline; position: absolute; right: 100px;'></div>" +
        "</div>";

    TemplatedListItem = declare("CustomListItem",
        [ListItem, TemplatedMixin], {
            label: "My label",
            size: "0",
            templateString: template
        }
    );
});
```

Here the html (jade) code:

```
h2(data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.RoundRectCategory") List
    #panel(data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/ScrollablePane")
        ul#list(data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/EdgeToEdgeStoreList" data-dojo-props="itemRenderer: CustomListItem, itemMap: {Desc: 'label', size: 'size'}, select: 'single'")
```

Finally, the js used to fill the list:

```
store = new Memory({data: JSON.parse(data), idProperty: "Desc"});
list.setStore(store);
```

Comment: Are you using/creating a widget? can you post a piece of code of your js/widget?

Comment: I'm just trying to use my custom ListItem in an EdgeToEdgeStoreList. I will add some other code to my question. If it won't enough please ask!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing to extend from `_WidgetsInTemplateMixin`, this mixin tells the template system that your template has other widgets in it and to instantiate them when your widget is instantiated. You can [read about it here](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/templated/index.html#the-_widgetsintemplatemixin-mixin).

An example of how you can use it in your code, read the comments:

```
define([
    "dojox/mobile/ListItem",
    "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
    "dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin", //Include this module
    "dojox/mobile/Badge",
    "dojo/_base/declare"
], function (ListItem, TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin, Badge, declare) {
    var template =
        "<div class='areaDone${done}'>" +
        "       <div style='display: inline;' data-dojo-attach-point='labelNode'></div>" +
        "       <div data-dojo-type='dojox/mobile/Badge' data-dojo-props='value:${size}' style='display: inline; position: absolute; right: 100px;'></div>" +
        "</div>";

    TemplatedListItem = declare("CustomListItem",
        [ListItem, TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin/*Extend*/], {
            label: "My label",
            size: "0",
            templateString: template
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: It works like a charm! I didn't understand the role of the template mixin. Furthermore I was afraid about include `dijit` components while developing for `dojox` hence the confusion!